# How can I change "\n" from to " " in char* string type?

Tags: c, string

```
char* changeEntertoSpace(char* s) {
    char* begin;
    begin = s;

    while (*begin != NULL) {
        if (*begin=="\n") {
            //*begin = " ";
            strcpy(begin," ");
        }
        begin++;
        }
    s = begin;
    return s;
}
```

This is my code, where I try to change from **<Enter>** to **<Space>** in my text string `s`. But this doesn't work.

Could you help me understanding what is my mistake?

Comment: What is the function supposed to return? Currently it returns a pointer to the terminating NUL (`'\0'`). It might be more useful to return a pointer to the modified string.

Answer (score 4):

In order to substitute a single char in a string, `strcpy()` is the wrong choice because it will always append the string terminator (`'\0'`) at the end of the copied string.

That's probably the reason why the string after the substituted `'\n'` *seems to disappear*.

You simply have to replace the single character:

```
char * changeEnterToSpace(char* s) {
    char * begin;
    begin = s;

    while (*begin != '\0')
    {
        if (*begin=='\n')
        {
            *begin = ' '; // Substituting the single character
        }
        begin++;
    }
    // s = begin; 
    return s;
}
```

The assignment you commented before trying `strcpy()` was *almost* correct. You used double quotes to enclose space, but in C single characters are enclosed by single quotes: `char c = 'a'`.

Please note that, in order to find the character to be substituted, standard `strchr()` function can be used ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)).

**Note**: I also commented `s = begin;` assignment, that would make your function return an empty string. You instead probably want to return the original string after newlines replacement.

Comment: You may consider using `strchr()` to simplify the code.

Comment: I know, but it is probably easier for the OP an answer showing the punctual mistake in his/her attempt.

Answer (score 2):

`strchr()` is the function you need. It looks for a character in a string and returns a pointer to the first occurrence. You can loop on your string to find and replace all `'\n'` characters.

Code could be like:

```
#include <string.h>

char* changeEntertoSpace(char* s) {
    while(1) {
        char* found = strchr(s, '\n');
        if (found == NULL) {
            break;   
        } else {
            *found = ' ';    
        }        
    }
    return s;
}

// --------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char value[] = "hello,\nworld\n,what's up?";
    puts(value);
    changeEntertoSpace(value);
    puts(value);
}
```

You can optimize the function a little:

```
char* changeEntertoSpace(char* s) {
    char* found = s;
    while(1) {
        found = strchr(found, '\n');
        if (found == NULL) {
            break;   
        } else {
            *found = ' ';    
        }        
    }
    return s;
}
```

This way, you don't search the entire string each time, just the part after the occurrence.