# Replace underscore with white spaces and make the first letter of the name and the surname to upper case

Tags: c

i want to replace _ (underscore) with white spaces and make the first letter of the name and the surname to upper case while printing the nameList in searchKeyword method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void searchKeyword(const char * nameList[], int n, const char keyword[])
{
    int i,name=0;
    char *str;
    const char s[2] = " " ;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        char *str = (char *) malloc((strlen(nameList[0])+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str,nameList[i]);
        strtok(str,"_");

        if(strcmp(keyword,strtok(NULL,"_"))==0) // argument NULL will start string 
        {                                       // from last point of previous string
            name++;
            if(nameList[i] == '_')
            strcpy(nameList[i],s);
            //nameList[i] = ' ';
            printf("%s\n",nameList[i]);
        }
    }

    if(name==0)
    {
        printf("No such keyword found\n");
    }
    free(str); //deallocating space
}

int main()
{
    char p1[] = "zoe_bale";
    char p2[] = "sam_rodriguez";
    char p3[] = "jack_alonso";
    char p4[] = "david_studi";
    char p5[] = "denzel_feldman";
    char p6[] = "james_bale";
    char p7[] = "james_willis";
    char p8[] = "michael_james";
    char p9[] = "dustin_bale";

    const char * nameList[9] = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9};

    char keyword[100];
    printf("Enter a keyword: ");
    scanf("%s", keyword);

    printf("\n");

    searchKeyword(nameList, 9, keyword);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%s\n",nameList[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Search through the strings and print the ones whose surname part is equal to keyword.

As shown in the example runs below, the strings are printed in “Name Surname” format (the first letters are capitalized).

Output should be like this:

```
Enter a keyword: james

Michael James

zoe_bale

sam_rodriguez

jack_alonso

david_studi

denzel_feldman

james_bale

james_willis

michael_james

dustin_bale
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there something in particular you're having trouble with?

Comment: @RetiredNinja i need to replace "_" (underscore) with white spaces and make the first letter of the name and the surname to upper case while printing the nameList in searchKeyword method.

Comment: Okay, so you've included code. Does that code not do what you want?

Comment: @RetiredNinja no it does not. I couldn't make it can you please help?

Comment: It would be best for you to focus the question better on the problem you're having. Presumably that code does something but not everything. What's wrong with it? Here's a tip though, `token = strtok(NULL, "-");` A dash `-` is not the same as an underscore `_`.

Comment: also I guess that the checking for the keyword should be done for all names and not just the last one. Put it into the loop.

Comment: @nicksheen i edit my code can you check this one please

Comment: @RetiredNinja  i edit my code can you check this one please

Comment: if you are allocating memory in each iteration then it's not enough to free it one time. It definitely has got memory leaks

Comment: @nicksheen this is not the problem. In the output, i want to delete the underscore and make the name and surnames first letter to upper case which is shown above. For example my output is like zoe_bale but I want Zoe Bale.

Comment: Talking about the substitution part, I answered to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853207/11336762) some time ago. What you need to add is just to switch to uppercase the first letter of the array (first name) and the first letter after the underscore.

Comment: `char *str = (char *) malloc((strlen(nameList[0])+1)*sizeof(char));` should be `str = malloc (strlen (nameList[i]) + 1);` (declaration *shadows* `char *str;` above and `sizeof (char)` is `1` and should be omitted), and [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Then `if (nameList[i] == '_')` is a comparison between a *pointer* and *integer* and will not work (do not ignore compiler warnings -- do not accept code until it compiles without warning)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to dynamically allocate storage for your name and surname. Looking at your input, neither will exceed 9-characters, so simply using an array for each of 64-chars provides 6X the storage required (if you are unsure, double that to 128-chars and have 1200% additional space). That avoids the comparatively expensive calls to `malloc`.

To check whether `keyword` exists in `nameList[i]`, you don't need to separate the values first and then compare. Simply use `strstr (nameList[i], keyword)` to determine if `keyword` is contained in `nameList[i]`. If you then want to match only the `name` or `surname` you can compare again after they are separated. (up to you)

To parse the names from the `nameList[i]` string, all you need is a single pointer to locate the `'_'` character. A simple call to `strchr()` will do and it does not modify `nameList[i]` so there is no need to duplicate.

After using `strchr()` to locate the `'_'` character, simply `memcpy()` from the start of `nameList[i]` to your pointer to your `name` array, increment the pointer and then `strcpy()` from `p` to `surname`. Now you have separated `name` and `surname`, simply call `toupper()` on the first character of each and then output the names separate by a space, e.g.

```
...
#include <ctype.h>

#define NLEN 64

void searchKeyword (const char *nameList[], int n, const char keyword[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* loop over each name in list */
        if (strstr (nameList[i], keyword)) {    /* does name contain keyword? */
            char name[NLEN], surname[NLEN];     /* storage for name, surname */
            const char *p = nameList[i];        /* pointer to parse nameList[i] */
            if ((p = strchr(p, '_'))) {         /* find '_' in nameList[i] */
                /* copy first-name to name */
                memcpy (name, nameList[i], p - nameList[i]);
                name[p++ - nameList[i]] = 0;    /* nul-terminate first name */
                *name = toupper (*name);        /* convert 1st char to uppwer */
                /* copy last name to surname */
                strcpy (surname, p);
                *surname = toupper (*surname);  /* convert 1st char to upper */

                printf ("%s %s\n", name, surname);  /* output "Name Surname" */
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Used with the remainder of your code, searching for `"james"` locates those names containing `"james"` and provides what looks like the output you requested, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/keyword_surname
Enter a keyword: james

James Bale
James Willis
Michael James

zoe_bale
sam_rodriguez
jack_alonso
david_studi
denzel_feldman
james_bale
james_willis
michael_james
dustin_bale
```

(**note:** to match only the `name` or `surname` add an additional `strcmp` before the call to `printf` to determine which you want to output)

**Notes On Your Existing Code**

Additional notes continuing from the comments on your existing code,

```
char *str = (char *) malloc((strlen(nameList[0])+1)*sizeof(char));
```

should simply be

```
str = malloc (strlen (nameList[i]) + 1);
```

You have previously declared `char *str;` so the declaration before your call to `malloc()` *shadows* your previous declaration. If you are using gcc/clang, you can add `-Wshadow` to your compile string to ensure you are warned of shadowed variables. (they can have dire consequences in other circumstances)

Next, `sizeof (char)` is always `1` and should be omitted from your size calculation. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc()` in C. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Your comparison `if (nameList[i] == '_')` is a comparison between a *pointer* and *integer* and will not work. Your compiler should be issuing a diagnostic telling you that is incorrect (do not ignore compiler warnings -- do not accept code until it compiles without warning)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me and has no memory leaks.

```
void searchKeyword(const char * nameList[], int n, const char keyword[])
{
    int found = 0;
    const char delim = '_';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const char *fst = nameList[i];

        for (const char *tmp = fst; *tmp != '\0'; tmp++) {
            if (*tmp == delim) {
                const char *snd = tmp + 1;

                int fst_length = (snd - fst) / sizeof(char) - 1;
                int snd_length = strlen(fst) - fst_length - 1;

                if (strncmp(fst, keyword, fst_length) == 0 ||
                        strncmp(snd, keyword, snd_length) == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                    printf("%c%.*s %c%s\n",
                           fst[0]-32, fst_length-1, fst+1,
                           snd[0]-32, snd+1);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        puts("No such keyword found");
}
```

hopefully it's fine for you too, although I use `string.h`-functions very rarely.