# How to get rid of a new line after string

Tags: c, printf

I was trying to print a string and an integer using array of structs and code seems to be fine, but in the output instead of 1 line of values, after each string a new line is automatically added. Can someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef
    struct player_main{
        char name[20];
        int total;
    }
player;

void print(player pprint);
void scan(player *pscan);

int main(){
    player user[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){// scanned
        printf("Player %d", i+1);
        scan(&(user[i]));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){// printed
        print(user[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
void print(player pprint){
    printf("%s Weight:%d kg\n", pprint.name, pprint.total);

}
void scan(player *pscan){
    printf("\nName: \n");
    fgets(pscan->name, 20, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter weight:");
    scanf("%d%*c", &(pscan->total));

}
```

**Example of desired output**:

```
Player A, 50 kg    Player B, 60 kg
```

**Actual output**:

```
Player A,
50 kg
Player B,
60 kg
```

Comment: Can you share a sample output ?

Comment: This can't be you actual output. It does not match the code.

Comment: @EugeneSh.It could, if the player name was `A,\n` (i.e. with a trailing newline), which using `fgets()` would do.

Comment: @TripeHound It is missing "Weight" word,

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right... I was focused on the newlines :-)

Comment: @EugeneSh Thanks very much! And yes the word Weight isn't where it must be as it was just an example output, sorry for that

Comment: @AhmadLabouff all you have to do is substitute a single char to the string obtained with fgets. I answered [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853207/11336762) some times ago.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` adds \n (the 'enter' you press) to the buffer.

You can use `strchr` to replace it with '\0';

```
void scan(player *pscan){
    ...
    *strchr(pscan->name, '\n') = '\0';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` also reads the newline character into the buffer, you will need to remove it:

```
//...
fgets(pscan->name, 20, stdin);
pscan->name[strcspn(pscan->name, "\n")] = '\0';
//...
```

Include `string.h`.

[Running code](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy997ilYL)